# Copy specific columns from one table to another table, and include the source tablename

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have this newly created table in SQL Server with 3 columns `ID, Name, Source`.

Basically this table will be populated with data from other different tables, each specifically taking in their record IDs and record Names. I believe this can be easily achieved with an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

I would like to find out on how to populate the `Source` column. This column is supposed to indicate which table the data came from. For example, `Source` in table A has 3 records, which I then copied the `ID` and `Name` columns from this table, and put it into my destination table.

At the same time, the 3 new records will have their `Source` column set, indicating it came from Table A. Then I will proceed to do the same for other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the constant string as follows:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
SELECT id, name, 'TableA' as source
  FROM tableA
```